# formula to find the difference between time with a conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula to find the difference between 2 time, and also have a condition like this :

> If work time > 8 hours, then the difference from work time become the overtime

And here's the image of my table in Excel :
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X00qZ.png)
Can you please tell me what to write the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula for worktime

`=F2-E2`

Formula for Overtime

`=MAX(G2-(1/3),0)`

[image]

If you would like the work time and overtime to be formatted as number (e.g 1 instead of 1:00), use the formulas below and format your cells to be numbers

`=(F2-E2)*24`
`=MAX(G2-8,0)`